# Scrapy Max Redirect issue

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

i am just trying to crawl a single page

```
start_urls = ['https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm']
```

but redirecting again and again, at the end scrapy **Discard** it

although i tried to

```
REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES=100
```

this setting as well but still its redirecting 100 times and scrapy **Discard** it

any help would be appreciated

here is the log.

```
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:53+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] DEBUG: Discarding <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>: max redirections reached
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>: 
2012-04-02 20:10:54+0500 [mileageplusshopping] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

**i am on scrapy 0.14**

here is my setting class

```
BOT_NAME = 'mall_crawler'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['mall_crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'mall_crawler.spiders'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8'

RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1   

HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True    
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': None,
}

SCHEDULER_ORDER = 'BFO'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found solution so i would like to share you people

its just because of

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
```

actually the start_url is `https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm`

that redirects to `https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false`

that redirects to `https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm`

and finally that redirects to `https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm`

if you look on first request and last request both are **same**

thats why at last request it found this request in **cache** and a loop starts on, so if we do not cached the pages all is well.

or we need to handle all this manually if we want to cache the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a `REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES` issue. I think it is just a redirect issue.

You must find out why the web page redirects you.

Why? Possibilities:

1. Looking at your [`USER_AGENT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) (i think this is the most probable)
2. Looking at your cookies.
3. It performs some actions using Javascript, which is obviously "disabled" in scrapy.
4. Or a combination of these.

UPDATE:

I did a test spider for that site, and looks like it's not a simple site. Firefox log shows this:

```
[10:21:45.707] GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 2128ms]
[10:21:47.856] GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false [HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 517ms]
[10:21:48.375] GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 1664ms]
[10:21:50.042] GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3818ms]
[10:21:53.230] GET https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/35975/5d/i.mallnetworks.com/images/css/united/mn_brand_united_noncardholder.css [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 446ms]
```

The conclusion i have now is that the browser is also redirected, the redirection is done ok. Have to research further (i am not that expert).

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Actually the spider works ok here:

```
class TestSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "mileageplusshopping_com"
    allowed_domains = ["mileageplusshopping.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print 'here'
```

Running:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/test$ scrapy crawl mileageplusshopping_com
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.2 started (bot: test)
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] INFO: Spider opened
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2012-04-03 10:30:40+0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-04-03 10:30:42+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false> from <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-03 10:30:43+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/sso/LoginBridge.aspx?target=/shopping/b____alpha.htm&redirect=sec&targetURLKey=cartua.bridge.url&remove=false>
2012-04-03 10:30:44+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> from <GET https://x.www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm>
2012-04-03 10:30:47+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.mileageplusshopping.com/shopping/b____alpha.htm> (referer: None)
here
2012-04-03 10:30:47+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-04-03 10:30:47+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 1140,
         'downloader/request_count': 4,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 68882,
         'downloader/response_count': 4,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 3,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 3, 7, 30, 47, 879869),
         'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 4,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 3, 7, 30, 40, 250275)}
2012-04-03 10:30:47+0300 [mileageplusshopping_com] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2012-04-03 10:30:47+0300 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
        {'memusage/max': 88838144, 'memusage/startup': 88838144}
vic@wic:~/projects/test$
```

Comment: currently i tried this "USER_AGENT" 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8' but in vain, i don't have any grip of points that you mentioned other then first one, so kindly can you please tell me what exactly is the issue..thank you

Comment: @akhterwahab actually the test spider works ok here, see the another update. The sources: http://www.sendspace.com/file/rf6i4k

Comment: can you please tel me what are your settings and version of scrapy ? currently i am using scrapy 14

Comment: i use ubuntu. Used `sudo pip install Scrapy` to install scrapy 0.14.2. see the sources in the comment above

Comment: i am also on scrapy 0.14.2 but on windows my settings class is now also associated with question but still not able to crawl this page using scrapy :(